# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in two-way Angular binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XD9YrIjiy8py7J78SRVW?p=preview):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>{{ foo }}</h1>    
      <bpp [(foo)]="foo"></bpp>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  foo;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'bpp',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{ foo }}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Bpp {
  @Input('foo') foo;

  @Output('fooChange') fooChange = new EventEmitter();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const potentiallyButNotNecessarilyAsyncObservable = Observable.of(null);

    potentiallyButNotNecessarilyAsyncObservable.subscribe(() => {
      this.fooChange.emit('foo');
    })
  }
}
```

where error occasionally appears:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'foo'

It results from the fact that two-way binding is updated by an observable that can get a value on same tick. I would prefer to not wrap the logic above with `setTimeout` because it looks like a hack and complicates control flow

What can be done to avoid this error here?

Does `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error have ill effects or can it be ignored? If it can, can change detector be silent on it and not pollute the console?

Comment: I never get that error but have you tried using async pipe ? may be that helps.

Comment: @fastAsTortoise A pipe is not applicable here The error will appear regardless of the template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's first unwrap the two-way data binding to simplify explanation:

```
<div>
  <h1>{{ foo }}</h1>    
  <bpp [foo]="foo" (fooChange)="foo=$event"></bpp>
</div>
```

It still has the same effect and occasionally produces the error. The error will only be produced if the `potentiallyButNotNecessarilyAsyncObservable` is synchronous. So we can also replace this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const potentiallyButNotNecessarilyAsyncObservable = Observable.of(null);

    potentiallyButNotNecessarilyAsyncObservable.subscribe(() => {
      this.fooChange.emit('foo');
    })
```

with this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.fooChange.emit('foo');
```

This case falls into the `Synchronous event broadcasting` category of errors that is explained in the article [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4#ea64).

The `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook is triggered after the parent component changes have been processed. The order of hooks related to child components is explained in the [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f). Now Angular remembers that when it ran change detection for the `App` component the value of `foo` was `undefined`, but during validation phase the value is `foo` that is updated by the child `Bpp` component. Hence it produces the error.

> What can be done to avoid this error here?

The fixes and the problems are described in the article I linked. The only safe option here if you don't want to redesign you logic is asynchronous update. You could also run change detection for the parent component but they may lead to an infinite loop since change detection on a component triggers change detection for component's children.

> Does ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error have ill
>   effects or can it be ignored?

The ill affect is that you will have incosistent state in the application `App.foo==='foo'` and the view `{{foo}}===undefined` until the next [digest cycle](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angulars-digest-is-reborn-in-the-newer-version-of-angular-718a961ebd3e) iteration. The error cannot be turned off in the development mode but it will not appear in the production mode.

[Two Phases of Angular Applications](https://vsavkin.com/two-phases-of-angular-2-applications-fda2517604be) is also pretty good in explaining the mental model for this error.

Comment: I am having a similar problem (which I fixed with detectChanges). And I am too emiting to an Output after subscribing to an Observable. But how is that emission synchronous if it is done after subscribing to an Observable?

Comment: @Bernardo, I'd need to see a stackblitz demo and code to answer your question